# How do I break up my vuex file?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a vuex file with a growing mass of mutators, but I'm not sure of the correct way of splitting it out into different files.

Because I have:

`const store = new Vuex.Store({ vuex stuff })` and then below that my main Vue app declaration: `const app = new Vue({ stuff })`

I'm happy working with Vue components and have lots of those already, but this is stuff at the top level of the app and I'm not sure how to break it apart. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 45):

For those who would like to break up the Vuex file without creating a more complex modular application structure, I think it is also possible to simply break the actions, mutations and getters into separate files like this:

```
└── src
     ├── assets
     ├── components
     └── store
           ├── store.js
           ├── actions.js
           ├── mutations.js
           └── getters.js
```

### store.js

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import Vue from 'vue';

import actions from './actions';
import getters from './getters';
import mutations from './mutations';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    someObj: {},
  },
  actions,
  getters,
  mutations,
});
```

### actions.js

```
const actionOne = (context) => {
  ...
  context.commit('PROP1_UPDATED', payload);
};

const actionTwo = (context) => {
  ...
  context.commit('PROP2_UPDATED', payload);
};

export default {
  actionOne,
  actionTwo,
};
```

### mutations.js

```
const PROP1_UPDATED = (state, payload) => {
  state.someObj.prop1 = payload;
};

const PROP2_UPDATED = (state, payload) => {
  state.someObj.prop2 = payload;
};

export default {
  PROP1_UPDATED,
  PROP2_UPDATED,
};
```

### getters.js

```
const prop1 = state => state.someObj.prop1;
const prop2 = state => state.someObj.prop2;

export default {
  prop1,
  prop2,
};
```

...then you are able to do stuff from within your components as you please using the usual `this.$store.dispatch('actionOne')` ...

Comment: This results in "getters should be function but "getters.default" in module "modulename" is {}."

Comment: In current version you should not use the keyword "default" at the exports!!

Comment: @Roel - this pattern of getters is working fine at my end. Could you share a code example perhaps so I could take a look? Happy to edit if required.

Comment: When I changed my export to `export { … }` it worked for me!  Removed the default keyword.

Comment: @bjbk interesting that you found that too. Maybe we have a slightly different project set up... or maybe Roel is right and it's a version thing (although that feels less likely). either way, glad you got it working anyway! :)

Comment: I think it is because I have an index.js for each store module. I noticed that exports the entire module.

Comment: hmmm... I gave the example using the global store but I also have modular stores using the same pattern and and index.js for each one. i still use the `export default { }` syntax throughout. I have each of the modular stores namespaced - perhaps that it something to do with it?

Comment: ...each module's index.js ends thus: `export default { namespaced: true, state, actions, getters, mutations, };`

Comment: interesting.  I posted an answer with my setup that works.  Using es6 - js Standard style - Quasar Framework v1 beta.  Anyway, +1 from me as you helped me with my project!  Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome - glad I could help! Ah, maybe you had to remove the `default` part because you use the `import * as getters from ...` syntax, whereas I just `import getters from ...`?

Comment: @bigsee possibly. Js is fun, eh?

Answer (score 32):

**This is another option for splitting your store and have diferent modules, this is already tested.**

**structure**

```
└── src
    ├── assets
    ├── components
    └── store
       └─ modules
          └─ module1
              ├── state.js
              ├── actions.js
              ├── mutations.js
              ├── getters.js
              └── index.js
         └─ module2
              ├── state.js
              ├── actions.js
              ├── mutations.js
              ├── getters.js
              └── index.js
   └─ index.js
```

**store/index.js**

```
import Vuex from "vuex";
import thisismodule1 from "./modules/module1";
import thisismodule2 from "./modules/module2";

const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      module1: thisismodule1,
      module2: thisismodule2

    }
  });
};

export default createStore;
```

**store/modules/module1/index.js**

```
import actions from './actions';
import getters from './getters';
import mutations from './mutations';
import state from './state';


export default {
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters
}
```

**store/modules/module2/index.js**

```
import actions from './actions';
import getters from './getters';
import mutations from './mutations';
import state from './state';


export default {
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters
}
```

**Tipp: Don't forget to import your store to your main.js**

Documentation: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To convince be otherwise please explain how this works and why it is supposed to solve the problem.

Comment: It does works, it is tested. This is divided into diferent modules

Comment: The OP doesn't mention a modular application structure of the application but perhaps useful for other people with more complex use cases than the OP.

Comment: Since [@bjbk already put a good modular example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55310269/5591135), perhaps it would have been better and tidier for future readers just to add your store/index.js to that existing response. Or have you added something else that I've missed? :)

Answer (score 15):

You can break them into different modules. That way you can keep all related mutations, getters, state and actions in separate files. The documentation explains it better than I can: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html

Comment: As expected, my attempts at doing this have resulted in `store is not defined` errors on the very first store.commit in the first component.

Comment: That's not enough detail to give any help.

Comment: Here is example code on how to break it https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/shopping-cart/store

Answer (score 7):

In addition to [@bigsee's fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50306081/4727183), if using an `index.js` file to export the module:

```
└── src
    ├── assets
    ├── components
    └── store
          └─ mymodule
              ├── state.js
              ├── actions.js
              ├── mutations.js
              ├── getters.js
              └── index.js
```

### index.js

```js
import state from './state'
import * as getters from './getters'
import * as mutations from './mutations'
import * as actions from './actions'

export default {

  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

### getters.js

```js
const getData = state => state.data

export {
  getData
}
```

Similar with actions, mutations and state files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this structure with dynamically load store modules.

```
src
└─ store
   └─ modules
      └─ [module-name].js
      └─ ...
   └─ index.js // <- your store main file
```

and in *index.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

// Load store modules dynamically.
const requireContext = require.context('./modules', false, /.*\.js$/)

const modules = requireContext.keys()
  .map(file =>
    [file.replace(/(^.\/)|(\.js$)/g, ''), requireContext(file)]
  )
  .reduce((modules, [name, module]) => {
    if (module.namespaced === undefined) {
      module.namespaced = true
    }

    return { ...modules, [name]: module }
  }, {})

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules
})
```

after that, just put your module *[name].js* in *modules* folder, eg:
**auth.js:**

```
// state
export const state = {}

// getters
export const getters = {}

// mutations
export const mutations = {}

// actions
export const actions = {}
```

to access your actions/getters.. You must write:

```
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      method_1: '[module-name]/method_1',
      method_2: '[module-name]/method_2',
    }),
    method_with_arg(){
      return this.$store.getters['[module-name]/method_with_arg'](this.n)
    }
  },
...
```

You can find demo [here (laravel-vue-spa)](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-vue-spa) by ***Cretu Eusebiu***.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i have this structure:

```
└── store
          └─ module1
              ├── actions.js
              ├── mutations.js
              ├── getters.js
              └── index.js
   index.js
```

and you can copy this example code :
index.js from module1

```
    import actions from "./actions";
    import getters from "./getters";
    import mutations from "./mutations";
    
    import { state } from "./state";

    export default {
     state: () => state,
     actions,
     mutations,
     getters,
   };
```

state:

```
export let state = {
  themes: [],
};
```

getters:

```
const themesList = (state) => {
  return state.themes;
};
```

actions:

```
const getThemesList = async ({ commit }) => {
  
  commit(types.GET_THEMES, [values]);
};
```

mutations:

```
const GET_THEMES = (state, themes) => {
  state.themes = themes;
};
```

and in the main index.js in store put this

```
const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      module1: module1,
    },
  });
};

export default createStore;
```

Answer (score 0):

For more nested moudles, you can export 'modules' in sub-module.

How to expose moudles in sub module?

```js
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import Vue from 'vue';
import actions from './actions';
import getters from './getters';
import mutations from './mutations';
import moudles from './moudles';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    someObj: {},
  },
  actions,
  getters,
  mutations,
  moudles,
});
```

```
└── src
    ├── assets
    ├── components
    └── store
       └─ modules
          └─ module1
              ├── state.js
              ├── actions.js
              ├── mutations.js
              ├── getters.js
              └── index.js
              ├── modules
                 |____moudleA （state.js.....）
                 |____moudleB （state.js.....）         
                  
         └─ module2
              ├── state.js
              ├── actions.js
              ├── mutations.js
              ├── getters.js
              └── index.js
   └─ index.js
```

More details pls refer to https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html