# Separating store into separate files (actions, mutations, getters) get api calls now not working

Tags: api, vue.js, action, vuex

I'm trying to spilt up my store firstly so all the getters, actions and mutations are in separate files as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50306081/5434053

I have API calls in a services file, the POST api calls seem to work but the GET ones do not, the action seems to get nothing back. Have I missed something?

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import actions from './actions';
import getters from './getters';
import mutations from './mutations';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    status: '',
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
    user: {},
    movie: {},
    movies: {}
  },
  actions,
  getters,
  mutations,
});
```

store/actions.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {APIService} from '../services/APIService';
const apiService = new APIService();

let getMovies = async ({commit, state, getter}) => {
    try {
      await apiService.getMovies(localStorage.getItem('token')).then((data, error) => {
        for (const movie of data.data.data.movies) {
          movie.edit = false;
          movie.deleted = false;
        }
        this.movies = data.data.data.movies;
        console.log(data)
        commit("fetch_movies", this.movies);        
      })
    } catch(error) {
      commit('auth_error')
      localStorage.removeItem('token')
      console.log(error)
    }
}

export default {
  getMovies,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are importing `actions` from `./actions`. However, when I look at your file at `store/actions.js` you are not exporting anything.

For JavaScript modules to work you have to add `export` statements to your files - so you can import the exported variables/properties somewhere else.

Also: You seem to only declare the function `getMovies()` without adding it to an `actions` object (which you import in `store.js`).

Try this:

```
// in store/actions.js

// your code..

const actions = {
  getMovies,
}

export default actions;
```

### Edit:

Just noticed you also use `this` in your action. If I am not mistaken it should be undefined as you only work with lambdas (Arrow Functions).

Comment: ah yes I am I just didn't include that bit sorry

Comment: @karl Just noticed you also you `this` in a context where it should be undefined if I'm not mistaken!

Comment: Yes missed that when I moved it from the component! Just noticed that myself! That's what the issue was.