# Vuex: unknown mutation type on modular application structure

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Instead of having a single file for state, actions, getters and mutations I implemented a separation by module.

Here's my application structure below:

[image]

Meaning, for every module I have, I have these files in place. Reason is that if I implemented it all in a single file per module, it gets bloated up. So I just separated by their functionality.

The problem is on my actions.js, I am getting `[vuex] unknown mutation type: FETCH_ITEMS_ACTION`

Here's my actions.js

```
export const actions = {
    fetchItemsAction: ({ commit, dispatch, getters }, { args } = {}) => {
        return axios(args).then((response) => {
            commit('FETCH_ITEMS_ACTION', response, {root: true})
        }
    }
}
```

And my mutations.js

```
export const mutations = {
    FETCH_ITEMS_ACTION: (state, dataTable) => {
        state.dataTable = dataTable;
    },
};
```

Comment: So you're "modularizing" a module? How are you merging the actions, mutations, getters, and state together? And how is the "modularized" module being added to the vuex store?

Comment: I am following this structure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564071/how-do-i-break-up-my-vuex-file

Comment: then can you please show the `store/index.js` and `store/ecommerce/index.js` file?

Comment: @basagabi Are those actions and mutations in one same module? And is the module itself `namespaced`?